# I have some leaks in init. I see no one leak

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm using leaks tool of instruments. It says that I have some leaks in the init method. It shows that NSMutableArray has leak.

I don't see any leaks.

```
@interface BookSettings : NSObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *authors;
@end

- (id)init 
{
   self = [super init];

   if(self) 
   {
    title           = [[NSString stringWithString:@""] retain];
    authors         = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
 [title release];
 [authors release];
 [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The provided code is OK, the problem is somewhere else where authors is retained without a balancing release. Leaks just points to the place ivar is created, not where the missing release should be. Check all the places where the retain count is increased.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the problem code to run, stop recording, search for there ivar of interest, drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

Seriously consider using ARC, there is little reason not to, ARC supports back to iOS 4.x.

BTW:

```
title = [[NSString stringWithString:@""] retain];
```

can be more compactly written:

```
title= @"";
```

Comment: I'am using some libraries, for example, ASIHHTP, it doesn't support ARC. That's why I don't use ARC.

Comment: ARC can be used on a per file basis but I understand your problem, 3rd party code can hold one back.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's from title.
You already have that property nonatomic, retain, so it this means a retain count of 1.

Then you specify another retain, making the retain count 2.

In the dealloc, you release it once, decreasing the retain count to 1. So this 1 reference that keeps retaining the string is the leak.

I don't understand why you are initialising the string like that anyway...

Comment: Yes, simple: `title = @"";` is all that is needed.

Comment: I think this is true for "authors" as well. You shoud NSLog a retain count for both author and title in dealloc NSLog("retain count %i / %i", [title retainCount], [authors retainCount]), right before you release them, and maybe again after releasing them.

Comment: Don't use retainCount, it almost never is what is expected, there are much better ways. Think in relatives, increases need to be balanced with decreases. See [retaincount is useless](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2011/12/18/retaincount-is-useless/) by bbum. Best: use ARC!

Comment: That's not exactly true. Anyway, his leak is right there, in the init. @Voloda2 just replace authors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; with authors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1]; [authors release]; This should fix your leak

Comment: No, notice that the assignment is to the ivar directly, not through the property accessor. `releasing `authors` at that point will dealloc it. Many feel it is good practice not to use accessors in `init` or `dealloc` methods. BTW, `initWithCapacity` is just extra cruft that basically accomplishes nothing.

Comment: I use the exact same method to init my mutable arrays and I have no leaks or crashes :P And initWithCapacity it's not a fix or anything, it's just the way I usually initialize the NSMutableArrays. It's either that or directly initWithArray and never simply init.

Comment: @Bogdan Bucur, I need to retain authors in init because I release it in dealloc, otherwise you'll release it twice. I don't use any properties in init.